# Listening to 2 guitar amps simultaneously

Tags: guitar, headphones

I want to listen to two amps at the same time through earphones( so as to not upset my neighbours). I already have a signal splitter between the guitar and the amps but am looking to plug my earphones into “something” so that I can then plug into the earphone socket of each amp! Does this sound ridiculous or is there something I can buy to achieve this?

Comment: A mixer. You want a mixer.

Comment: Honestly there's little point nowadays to use real amps if you can't use them _real loud_. Any decent digital simulation (like, VST plugins) will give better headphone results. There you can also easily experiment with running 2 amps in parallel (or 20, if you like).

Comment: @leftaroundabout the only problem is getting an audio card, getting rid of latency problem, and having a computer started every time... I agree with you but I personally prefer to deal with real hardware when possible ;)

Comment: I agree with @leftroundabout, and I would add Kemper or Line 6 and other amp sim solutions.

Answer (score 1):

Adding a little to Todd Wilcox's comment, the device you need is a mixer with panning controls. Pan channel 1 to one side and channel 2 to the other (or blend them to find a nice stereo image) and you will be able to hear both separately through the headphone out from the mixer.

Answer (score 1):

I use a *headphone mixer* 'Miniamp' by Behringer. 4 channels in, 4 out - all adjustable. Works nicely.